# Is flask_restful compatible with virtual environments?

Tags: api, virtualenv, flask-restful

I am making an API with Flask-RESTFUL, but when I make the POST

> http://127.0.0.1:5000/bot?id_articulo=1&url_articulo=www.wiki.org

I get the message

> "message": "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand."

My python code is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Bot(Resource):
    def post(self):
        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()  
        parser.add_argument('id_articulo' , required=True, type=int)
        parser.add_argument('url_articulo', required=True, type=str)
        args = parser.parse_args() 
        print(args)
        data_articulo = pd.read_csv('articulos.csv')
        print(data_articulo)
        if args['url_articulo'] in list(data_articulo['url']):
            return {
                'mensage': f"El artículo '{args['url_articulo']}' ya existe."
            }, 409
        else:
            nueva_columna = pd.DataFrame({
                'id_articulo':  [args['id_articulo']],
                'url': [args['url_articulo']],
            })

        data_articulo = data_articulo.append(nueva_columna, ignore_index=True)
        data_articulo.to_csv('articulos.csv', index=False)  
        return {'data': data_articulo.to_dict()}, 200 

api.add_resource(Bot, '/bot', methods=['POST'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Now, I noticed that the error message is thrown only when I am in a virtual environment whose requirements.txt is

```
aniso8601==9.0.1
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
joblib==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
numpy==1.23.1
pandas==1.4.3
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2022.1
six==1.16.0
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zipp==3.8.0
```

By this far, I don't have a clue about what is going on and it makes me think that the flask_restful library have issues with virtual environments and I would like to know how to make this work properly in one.

Comment: There should be no problem with virtual environments as such. Your "POST" request really looks like a GET request if you are only using that url with query parameters.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. But I think is really weird that when I'm not using the venv everything works good.

Comment: I would start by sending a post request since this is an endpoint for post requests. Take it from there.